# python kivy back to main menu button after clicking show black screen

Tags: python, android, kivy

Need help troubleshooting unresponsive "Main Menu" button on my website

Hello fellow forum members,I'm currently facing an issue with my app
black screen after clicking a "back to main menu" button in a Kivy application
However, when I click on the button, nothing happens. The menu doesn't expand, and there are no error messages or indications of what might be causing the issue.

```
my code: 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import random



KV = """

<MyBL>:
    name: "my_bl"
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: (0.95, 0.95)
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
    Label:
        font_size: "30sp"
        text: root.data_label
    Button:
        text: "1 przedzial"
        bold: True
        background_color: '#00FFCE'
        size_hint: (1, 0.5)
        on_press: root.add_up(1, 50, 100)
    Button:
        text: "2 przedzial"
        bold: True
        background_color: '#00FFCE'
        size_hint: (1, 0.5)
        on_press: root.add_up(2, 100, 200)
    Button:
        text: "3 przedzial"
        bold: True
        background_color: '#00FFCE'
        size_hint: (1, 0.5)
        on_press: root.add_up(3, 200, 400)
    Button:
        text: "4 przedzial"
        bold: True
        background_color: '#00FFCE'
        size_hint: (1, 0.5)
        on_press: root.add_up(4, 400, 800)
    Button:
        text: "5 przedzial"
        bold: True
        background_color: '#00FFCE'
        size_hint: (1, 0.5)
        on_press: root.add_up(5, 800, 1600)
    Button:
        text: "Stop"
        bold: True
        background_color: '#FF0000'
        size_hint: (1, 0.5)
        on_press: root.stop()
    Button:
        text: "Main Menu"
        bold: True
        background_color: '#00FFCE'
        size_hint: (1, 0.5)
        on_press: app.go_to_main_menu()

MainMenuBL:
    name: "main_menu"
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: (0.95, 0.95)
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
    Button:
        text: "Start"
        bold: True
        background_color: '#00FFCE'
        size_hint: (1, 0.5)
        on_press: app.go_to_my_bl()
"""

class MyBL(BoxLayout):
    data_label = StringProperty("Type number!")
    total_sum = 0

    def add_up(self, index, start, end):
        random_num = random.randint(start, end)
        self.total_sum += random_num
        self.data_label = f"Button {index}: {random_num}\n"

    def stop(self):
        self.data_label = f"Final Total Sum: {self.total_sum}"
        self.total_sum = 0

class MainMenuBL(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.current_screen = "main_menu"  # Set current screen to the initial screen name
        return self.root


    def go_to_my_bl(self):
        if self.current_screen != "my_bl":
            self.root.clear_widgets()
            self.root.add_widget(MyBL())
            self.current_screen = "my_bl"

    def go_to_main_menu(self):
        if self.current_screen != "main_menu":
            self.root.clear_widgets()
            main_menu = MainMenuBL()
            self.root.add_widget(main_menu)
            self.current_screen = "main_menu"

MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `kv` does not contain a rule for building an instance of `MainMenuBL`. The entry that starts with `MainMenuBL:` creates an instance of `MainMenuBL` with the attributes that follow it. To define a rule that defines how all instances of `MainMenuBL` should be created, you need to use `<MainMenuBL>:`. So, try updating your `kv` as :

```
<MainMenuBL>:
    name: "main_menu"
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: (0.95, 0.95)
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
    Button:
        text: "Start"
        bold: True
        background_color: '#00FFCE'
        size_hint: (1, 0.5)
        on_press: app.go_to_my_bl()
        
MainMenuBL:
```